# What observer needs to be use whenorder place

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-status

I am using Magento 1.9.

I am creating a module by using third party dropship API. I have an problem with order creation in Magento.

I am sending order details to third party website and want to save success order place in Magento after getting the true response from third party.

Here I am using `sales_order_place_after` Observer but it is creating order in Magento before a response comes.

If my response is false in this case Magento created the order successfully. Please suggest how can i do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dispatchEvent for create custom observer event. After getting response from api you can call dispatchEvent and place order.

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('custom_event', array('data' => $data));
```

TO define event you have to add code in config.xml of your module.

```
    <custom_event>
        <observers>
            <module_name>
                <class>module_name/observer</class>
                <method>observerFunction</method>
            </module_name>
        </observers>
    </custom_event>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` event to pass successful orders to your third party website.

`sales_order_place_after` event is triggered when place order button is clicked. after place order is clicked order gets placed and go through payment method some times payment method may return you success or failure message.

so appropriate event is `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`

In your config.xml file

```
<events>
    <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
        <observers>
            <push_order_to_thirdparty>
                <class>Yourpackagename_Yourmodulename_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>pushOrder</method>
            </push_order_to_thirdparty>
        </observers>
    </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
</events>
```

In your observer.php file

```
public function pushOrder($observer){
    $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
}
```